# Tcl/Tk: Set default back and fore ground formats for menu items

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I am having to set the same format for each object again and again, its a lot of code to write / maintain. Is there any configuration that allows to default the formatting of a widget like menubar.

Yes I can write a proc to handle this but just asking.

Condition illustrated in below example:

```
set menuBar .t.menubar
set wMenuBar [menu .t.menubar -bg #e6e6fa -activebackground #6495ed -fg #000080]
# .t configure -menu [menu .t.menubar -bg #e6e6fa -activebackground #6495ed -fg #000080 ] 
set fileMenu ${menuBar}.file
$menuBar  add cascade -label "File" -menu [menu $fileMenu -bg #e6e6fa -activebackground #6495ed -fg #000080] -underline 0 
$fileMenu add command -label "Save" -command { doTheSave } -underline 1 
$fileMenu add separator
$fileMenu add command -label "Quit" -command { destroy .t } -underline 0 

set logsMenu ${menuBar}.logs
$menuBar  add cascade -label "Logs" -menu [menu $logsMenu -bg #e6e6fa -activebackground #6495ed -fg #000080] -underline 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the [`option` command](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/option.htm) to set the widget-level defaults for menus.

```
option add *Menu.background "#e6e6fa"
option add *Menu.activeBackgrund "#6495ed"
option add *Menu.foreground "#000080"
```

The pattern description format is pretty obscure these days.